# Linq query selecting comma separated list

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list of objects where the object has a string property that is a comma separated list of numeric Ids.

What is most efficient way to extract the comma separated values and get an int array?

Currently my solution is this:

```
var allCsvs = objects
    .Select(o => o.IdCsv); // the IdCsv is a string property, ie "1,2,3,4,5"
var allIds = string.Join(",", allCsvs);
var idArray = allIds.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id));
```

Any ideas on how to improve performance here?

**Update:**

The object might look like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public string IdCsv { get; set; }
}
```

And an instance of this class may have its string property `IdCsv` set to something like this: `"1,2,3,4,5"`

Comment: Just to understand, is `IdCsv` already a string of comma separated ids ?

Comment: `.Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id));;` this part was not in your original question, which made me think that you want to parse string list to int array.

Comment: Please show us the class behind `objects`, what's `IdCsv`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
internal class Csv
{
    public string CommaSepList { get; set; }
}


var allCsvs =
    new List<Csv>
        {
            new Csv
                {
                    CommaSepList = "1,2,3,4,,5"
                },
            new Csv
                {
                    CommaSepList = "4,5,7,,5,,"
                },
        };

int[] intArray =
    allCsvs
        .SelectMany(c => c.CommaSepList.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToArray();
```

Or

```
int[] intArray =
    allCsvs
        .SelectMany(c => c.CommaSepList.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse))
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Works only if `idCSV` is a string and not an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter From OP "// the IdCsv is a string property, ie "1,2,3,4,5""

Comment: For clarification though :) The first sentence contains everything you need to know "I have a list of objects where the object has a string property that is a comma separated list of numeric Ids"

Comment: I check all solutions, and looks like this is a bit faster another and a bit shorter.

Comment: As I was commenting on Tim's answer, I have tried this solution. In fact, this was my first solution. Performing the string split in each iteration is worse than the solution I have in my question.